# Equation to bell-shaped (gaussian) curve matching specific criteria

Tags: graphing-functions, gaussian-integral

*please forgive my lack of math terminology being a developer myself*. I am looking for the equation of a **bell-shaped** (gaussian-like) curve with the following characteristics:

- The X domain is -infinity to +infinity with real (**discrete**) numbers
- **The Y domain is 0 to 1**
- The function is defined by only 2 parameters (like $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the gaussian case, I will use this terminology even if it may not accurately apply)
- **The sum of all $y$ equals 1** (over all X)
- **The sum of all $y$ in [$\mu-\sigma$, $\mu+\sigma$] equals 0.5**
- Both points $\mu-\sigma$ and $\mu+\sigma$ are inflection points
- When $\sigma$ tends to $0$, the value $y(\mu)$ tends to $1$ but will not reach 0.5 as per previous hypothesis. Call the $\sigma=0$ an edge case.
- (I suppose, when $\sigma$ tends to infinity, the value $y(\mu)$ tends to $0$ but again will not reach it because of the sum requirement)

Is such a curve possible at all ?

Can you provide it :) ?

Looking for **Gaussian** does not lead to what I am looking for, do you have directions or keywords for it ?

Comment: What does it even mean to take the sum of $y(x)$ over all real numbers $x$? Do you mean an integral? Your question is not well-posed.

Comment: Assuming you mean an integral, second problem: Suppose the deviation $\sigma$ is close to zero. Then you want the maximum of $y(x)$ to be close to $1$, but you also want the integral of $y(x)$ over an interval of width $2\sigma$ to be close to $0.5$. This is impossible: the integral cannot be larger than the maximum times the width of the interval, i.e. $2\sigma$, which is close to zero.

Comment: The integral is the area under the curve, no ? However, indeed the sum of all Y for reals is infinity right !? Maybe this is because of the real domain, would it make more sense in a discrete domain (natural numbers to start) ?

Comment: In a discrete domain I don't see how you can have $y$ at the mean tend to $1$, while the sum of all $y$ near the mean equals $0.5$. The sum cannot be smaller than any of the values being added, unless some of those values are negative.

Comment: You are right... call the $\sigma=0$ an edge case. I thought 'tend to 1' because as $\sigma$ decreases $y(\mu)$ increases and the maximum possible is 1, but indeed it will never be more than some value below 0.5